# Why does this Magento 2 SKU whitespace removal script not work?

Tags: php, magento2, whitespace, sku

I'm trying to remove whitespace from existing product SKUs on a Magento 2 website, when I input the desired IDs and click "Trim" a small table appears (which presumably would display the successfully changed SKUs), but it appears to show no data, and the SKUs remain untrimmed.

Using Magento 2.3.7-p2

[Source](https://www.bay20.com/remove-white-space-from-sku-in-magento2-using-script/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE unspecified PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params =  $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('global');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trim Product SKU</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Trim Product SKU</h1>
    <div class="main-div">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label><?php echo "Product from";?></label>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['from']))?$_POST['from']:"" ?>"/>
                            <label class="suggestion-from">Product From</label>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label><?php echo "Product to";?></label>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="to" id="to" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['to']))?$_POST['to']:"" ?>"/>
                            <label class="suggestion-from">Product To</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input class="search-button" type="submit" title="Trim" value="Trim"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>   
<?php 
if($_POST){
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    echo "<table border='1' class='result-table'><thead><tr><td colspan='3'>Import Data</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Product Id</td><td>Trimmed SKU</td></tr>";
    trimSKU($from, $to);
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}

function trimSKU($from, $to){
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
     $collection = $productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',
                    array(
                        'from'=>$from,
                        'to'=>$to
                    ))
                ->load();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($collection as $product){
            $i++;
            if($i > $to || $i < $from) { continue; };
            $arr_string=explode(" ", $product->getSku());
            $string='';
            foreach($arr_string as $str){
                $string.=$str;
        }
            $sku=$string;

            if($product->getId()){
                $product->setSku($sku)->save();
                echo "<tr><td>". $product->getId()."</td><td>".$product->getSKU()."</td></tr>";
            }
        } 
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
<!DOCTYPE unspecified PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params =  $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('global');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trim Product SKU</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Trim Product SKU</h1>
    <div class="main-div">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label><?php echo "Product from";?></label>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['from']))?$_POST['from']:"" ?>"/>
                            <label class="suggestion-from">Product From</label>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label><?php echo "Product to";?></label>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="to" id="to" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['to']))?$_POST['to']:"" ?>"/>
                            <label class="suggestion-from">Product To</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input class="search-button" type="submit" title="Trim" value="Trim"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>   
<?php 
if($_POST){
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    echo "<table border='1' class='result-table'><thead><tr><td colspan='3'>Import Data</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Product Id</td><td>Trimmed SKU</td></tr>";
    trimSKU($from, $to);
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}

function trimSKU($from, $to){
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
     $collection = $productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',
                    array(
                        'from'=>$from,
                        'to'=>$to
                    ))
                ->load();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($collection as $product){
            $i++;
            if($i > $to || $i < $from) { continue; };
            $arr_string=explode(" ", $product->getSku());
            $string='';
            foreach($arr_string as $str){
              if($str){
               $string.=$str;
              }                
             }
            $sku=$string;

            if($product->getId()){
                $product->setSku($sku)->save();
                echo "<tr><td>". $product->getId()."</td><td>".$product->getSKU()."</td></tr>";
            }
        } 
    }

?>
```